# Why do my labels not obey my Auto Layout constraints when the height of the cell grows slightly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm setting up the position of my items in a custom UITableViewCell subclass through Auto Layout, and I'm confused why two labels aren't positioned where they're supposed to be when the cell grows.

This is what my cell looks like:

[image]

I set the "Title" label to be positioned from the left, top, and right. I set the "author" label to be positioned to the left edge of "Title", to the right edge of "1200", top from "Title" and from the bottom of the cell. I set 1200 and 1900 to be spaced from one another and from "author", and they have their bottoms aligned with "author".

However, when the cell grows, they look like this:

[image]

Where you can see the two numbers don't maintain their "bottom" alignment. Why is this?

For testing, here's a project where you can see it in action: http://cl.ly/412m2A223z1S

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- Your author label is over-defined, you have it track the object above as well as the container bottom. Get rid of the "Bottom Space to Superview" constraint.
- Use the baseline instead of the bottom to align the author with the 1900 and 1200 labels, they will line up nicer that way because the font is not identical.